# Prevent using abstract classes as property type

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract

Is it possible to prevent using abstract classes as property type?

I have a abstract base class being inherited in an abstract class with generic type, which in turn is inherited in classes with defined types.  Is it possible to "lock down" the abstract class with generic type, so it's not possible to use it as a property in other classes?

Here's an approximation of my situation.  I want to prevent the possibility of creating properties like `doubleFoo2`.  The `Foo<T>` should only be able to be inherited in other classes, and not be able to be used as a type directly.

Since I'm validating `PropertyType` of properties and their base types, this lead to me making a mistake it took me a while to find.  Here's a test of the code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OMHmGv

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    // Various generic properties and methods
}

public abstract class Foo<T> : FooBase 
{
    public Type ValueType { get { return typeof(T); } }
    public abstract T Value { get; set; }
}

public class DoubleFoo : Foo<double> 
{
    public override double Value { get; set; }
}

public class FooHandler
{
    public DoubleFoo doubleFoo1 { get; set; }
    public Foo<double> doubleFoo2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *Is it possible to "lock down" the abstract class with generic type, so it's not possible to use it as a property in other classes?* No, it's not possible. Why do you care about such a thing? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: May be you need to make it `internal` or `private`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi As i wrote: "Since I'm validating PropertyType of properties and their base types, this lead to me making a mistake it took me a while to find."  I.e. I want to avoid making the mistake again.

Comment: What you want to do isn't possible in C#. [Access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers) are the only tool for limiting type exposure. In my opinion you're wasting your time on this. Please explain what your goal is.

Comment: What mistake did you make?

Comment: @KobyDuck @CodingYoshi In one place I had used `DoubleFoo`, and in another place I had used `Foo<double>` by mistake.  This lead to not validating correctly when evaluating the property base type.  See the .NET Fiddle example.

Comment: @Oystein Property validation isn't cheap and only useful in very specific circumstances. Have a look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tuubTS) variant of your fiddle.

Comment: @KobyDuck Thanks for the tip. However, this approach won't work in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only it's impossible, it goes against one of the three basic principles of object oriented programming - and I'm talking, of course, about [polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism).
Giving up polymorphism is giving up object oriented programming altogether.

The point is that a reference of a type can actually refer to an instance of any type deriving from the reference type.

Polymorphism is what makes the following code line is perfectly valid (even though not very useful):

```
object s = "the type is actually a string but the reference is of type object";
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've only heard about polymorphism and don't know much about it.  Time to read up on it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Like what @Zohar Peled said, it defeats the purpose of polymorphism, restricting usage based on namespace or assembly is your only way.

If the DoubleFoo and its child classes are created in a seperate assembly, you may use the

> internal

modifier instead of

> public

for both FooBase and Foo classes to prevent other assemblies from access them.

If you have to use this DoubleFoo in the same assembly, you can try putting the base classes in the different namespace to hide the base implementation classes.
An example would be:

Inside FooOfT.cs

```
namespace FooTester.DoubleFoo.Foo
{
    public abstract class FooBase
    {
        // Various generic properties and methods
    }

    public abstract class Foo<T> : FooBase 
    {
        public Type ValueType { get { return typeof(T); } }
        public abstract T Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Inside DoubleFoo.cs

```
using FooTester.DoubleFoo.Foo

namespace FooTester.DoubleFoo
{
    public class DoubleFoo : Foo<double> 
    {
        public override double Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

inside FooHandler.cs

```
using FooTester.DoubleFoo

namespace FooTester
{
    public class FooHandler
    {
        public DoubleFoo doubleFoo1 { get; set; }
        // public Foo<double> doubleFoo2 { get; set; } Cannot access Foo<T> class
    }
}
```

Comment: All the classes are in the same assembly.  But good idea to use a separate namespace for the base classes.  At least I'll get a warning that the using statement needs to be added which will (hopefully) tell me I'm about to make a booboo.. :-)

Comment: You'll get warnings if you try to use a class from a different namespace. If you use this approach, you still can create different types of child Foo classes in the DoubleFoo namespace and keep the polymorphism going in that namespace.